# PostgreSQL COPY FROM csv with different date format

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to upload CSV data to a PostgreSQL database in Python using the COPY FROM STDIN function.

In the CSV file my Date field is DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI and this gives me an error:

> psycopg2.errors.DatetimeFieldOverflow: date/time field value out of
> range: "31-12-2020 08:09"

Is there a way I can define the Date/Time format when using COPY FROM?

DB column is type TIMESTAMP if relevant.

I only know how to do this with a line-by-line INSERT statement.

Comment: @S-Man apologies that was just me typing off the top of my head.  I am just copying from CSV with no Date format specified, I'll update for correctness. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that your database is expecting `2020-12-31` instead of `31-12-2020`? You could always import it to a text column and cast it to timestamp afterwards ;-) Would it be an option? Although postgres would cast it withnout any problems: `SELECT '31-12-2020 08:09'::timestamp` ;-)

Comment: @JimJones yes I believe PostgreSQL is expecting 2020-12-31 format but I don't know if this can be manipulated with the COPY FROM function. I assume using a temporary text column will still be considerable more efficient than having Python do a line-by-line file read & insert

Comment: It is indeed much more efficient to parse and transform data once they are inside of the database. And you're right: using INSERT statements would be terribly inefficient with large files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just before the `COPY` command do:

```
set datestyle = euro;

show datestyle;
 DateStyle 
-----------
 ISO, DMY
```

Then this works:

```
SELECT '31-12-2020 08:09'::timestamp;
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2020-12-31 08:09:00
```

Otherwise with my default `datestyle`:

```
show datestyle;
 DateStyle 
-----------
 ISO, MDY

SELECT '31-12-2020 08:09'::timestamp;
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "31-12-2020 08:09"
LINE 1: SELECT '31-12-2020 08:09'::timestamp;
```

For more information see here [Date input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) Table 8.15. Date Order Conventions

Comment: Thanks. I created temporary text columns to get the data loaded then in pgAdmin I used "UPDATE public.my_table SET actual_datetime_col=(SELECT str_datetime_col::timestamp)" to update.

Comment: You could save a step by just temporarily changing the `datestyle` setting in the session before you do the `COPY`.