# Import CSV with dates formatted "DDMMYYYY"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

I am trying to import a CSV file that contains dates whose format is `MMDDYYYY`, but Postgres is expecting `YYYYMMDD` and the CSV file keeps failing to load.

I have tried amending the CSV file in Excel and reloading, but the load still recognises the original date format of `MMDDYYYY`

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Examine the csv file using a simple text editor; is it *actually* YYYYMMDD or did you just change the way Excel formats dates (which has no effect on how Excel exports data to csv format)?

Comment: I have used the text editor which shows the date to be stored at DDMMYYYY - SQL will still not accept the file as SQL is expecting MMDDYYYY

Comment: What is your question then? Why is Excel saving the data in a particular format? That is a question that is off topic for this site. Also, your comment mentions `MMDDYYYY`, but that format is not mentioned in your question. I would use a text editor that can do regex replacement to correct the format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335662/postgresql-copy-from-csv-with-different-date-format

Comment: My question is the CSV file I am uploading holds the date format of MMDDYYYY. SQL is expecting YYYYMMDD. How do I enable SQL to accept the MMDDYYYY format?

Comment: Click the link in my previous comment